# Is true that $ \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} {\omega}_n \neq \emptyset $?

Tags: general-topology

Let ${\omega}_n$ dense in $\mathbb{C}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, with ${\omega}_{n} \subset {\omega}_{n-1}$. Is true that $ \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} {\omega}_n \neq \emptyset $?

If it true, is posible that $ \cap_{n=1}^{\infty} {\omega}_n$ dense in $\mathbb{C}$ ? Something like the Baire's Theorem.

Comment: Your condition $\omega_{n-1}\subseteq \omega_n$ implies

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \omega_n=\omega_1$$

so trivially it is dense by assumption.

Comment: Sorry, i mean $${\omega}_{n} \subset {\omega}_n-1$$. @AdamHughes

Comment: Let $(x_n)$ be an enumeration of a countable dense subset, $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ for example, and $\omega_n = \{ x_k : k \geqslant n\}$. If the $\omega_n$ are open, things are different.

Comment: Retagged to remove elementary-set-theory and set-theory. The notation $\omega_n$ has a particular conventional meaning in those fields which doesn't seem to be what is meant here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ be your favorite bijection $\mathbb N \to \mathbb Q[i]$ and then
$$ \omega_n = \{f(m)\mid m>n\} $$
Each of these sets is dense in $\mathbb C$, and their intersection is empty.

Of course it is also *possible* for the intersection to be dense, for example by choosing
$$ \omega_n = \{f(m)\mid m>n\} \cup \{z+\pi\mid z\in \mathbb Q[i]\} $$

Comment: Thanks, and if each ${\omega}_{n} $ is open? @henningmakholm

Comment: @Henfe: If each $\omega_n$ is open, then you can choose a sequence of nested _closed_ disks $D_1\supseteq D_2\supseteq \cdots \supseteq D_n \supseteq \cdots$ such that each $D_n\subseteq \omega _n$. The intersection of such a sequence of closed sets cannot be empty.